# bootstrap 4, react: how to change the title of a tooltip?

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, electron, bootstrap-4

If the user selects a different language in my electron/react/bootstrap 4 app, I want to change the text (title) of a bootstrap tooltip on a button.  I've read the [bootstrap 4 Tooltip doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options) and I can't figure out how to change the text of the bootstrap tooltip.

The title property of my button gets changed, but that does not change the text of the bootstrap 4 tooltip.  How can I change the text of the bootstrap 4 tooltip?

Answer (score 4):

I just found the answer:  use the `data-original-title` property and NOT the `title` property in the `<button>`.